# Getting error " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier " during fetching a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I want to get data from a json file, the json file is accessing but i am getting this error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier) at console. The error line is at the success function. 
What is the error I can not understand. 
Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

My code sample is below

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        "id": "aaaa",        
        "name" : "bbbbb",
        "title" : "cccc"
    }
});
var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book, 
});
var Allbooks = new Books();
Allbooks.fetch({
    url: "book.json",   
    dataType:'json',
    contentType:'application/json'
    success:function()  {
        console.log(Allbooks);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error in loading and processing the JSON file');
    }
});
```

my json file(book.json) is below

```
[{  
    "id": "aaaa3",        
    "name" : "bbbbb3",
    "title" : "cccc3",
},{ 
    "id": "aaaa1",        
    "name" : "bbbbb1",
    "title" : "cccc1",
},{
    "id": "aaaa2",        
    "name" : "bbbbb2",
    "title" : "cccc2",
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Is should be

```
success:function(response)  {
   console.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a comma at the end of the previous line to continue the object.

```
Allbooks.fetch({ 
url: "book.json",   
 dataType:'json',
 contentType:'application/json', // <<< that's where it was missing
success:function()  {
      console.log(Allbooks);
  },
error: function(){
   console.log('error in loading and processing the JSON file');
}
```

Comment: after adding comma the new error(XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Sm/Desktop/srm/book.json. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. ) is showing.

Comment: You can't make AJAX requests from `file:///` URLs. You need to put it on a server.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers, your json is invalid too. json should look like this

```
[{
    "id": "aaaa3",
    "name": "bbbbb3",
    "title": "cccc3"  << removed comma from here
}, {
    "id": "aaaa1",
    "name": "bbbbb1",
    "title": "cccc1"  << removed comma from here
}, {
    "id": "aaaa2",
    "name": "bbbbb2",
    "title": "cccc2" << removed comma from here
}]
```